# Does OS X file organization works like Ubuntu's?

Tags: macos, uti, unix

I mean, does mac have a "home" folder, and if I want to format and reinstall the system, it'll not affect my home folder? And the Desktop is a folder within the home folder?

Comment: For further reference, don't hesitate reading http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4125/115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OS X does indeed have a *home* folder, in /Users/<username> with a hierarchy of folders, including one for Desktop, in this location - similar to Ubuntu.

On most Linux distributions the /home is a different partition on the drive and formatting the primary OS partition would not erase your data. This is not the case with OS X and (unless you've made a concerted effort to the contrary) **erasing the OS X drive will erase your data**.

Comment: However you can reinstall the OS without deleting the /Users directory

Comment: @Mark that's an override? Or it's delete all files and reinstall?

Comment: @Tom The default install for OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) preserves /Users

Comment: @jtjacques that's an override of the system files? Or it's delete all system files and recopy?

Comment: It is an overwrite - but I would not rely on the result as the unwritten over files might not match the OS

Comment: @Mark I think its smarter than that.  It selectively deletes system directories and applications and replaces them.  So there shouldn't be anything left behind that the os cares about.