# Where should I store command line applications?

Tags: applications, command-line, filesystem

When I download command line applications they are located in my `~/Downloads/` directory. But I feel this is wrong place to have a command line application located. Where in the Mac OS X filesystem should I store command line applications?

`/Applications/` also feels wrong, it´s more for desktop applications. And `/bin/` sounds more for applications that belongs to OS X.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment that putting things directly in /bin or /Applications is generally poor form. Patrix's answer is the most canonical location I've seen for general command line storage of programs and scripts.

Comment: Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/80902/20459

Comment: I don't see these as duplicate since the [linked question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80902/where-should-shell-tools-be-installed?lq=1) seems more about juggling several third party choices and this is more a pure - where do my manually downloaded apps go.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since OS X comes from a unix heritage, you will want to store system files in `/usr/local/bin` for command line applications and scripts that belong to the system locally and not to a specific user. You may need to create this directory first by running:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

You can move any command line application to that folder by running:

```
sudo mv my-binary /usr/local/bin/
```

To make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is part of your standard search path in Terminal, check the content of `/etc/paths` and add it if necessary:

```
grep -w /usr/local/bin /etc/paths || sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin >> /etc/paths'
```

---

Some users make a second directory for user level scripts, but this is even more subject to personal preference.

I typically make a bin directory in each user folder and then hide it from Finder - but you can make that decision yourself whether you want it hidden:

```
 mkdir ~/bin
 chflags hidden ~/bin
```

In this case, you'll want to have each user's path include this location by modifying the shell startup scripts (`~/.bash_profile` for bash which is the standard shell)

```
 export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

or by hard coding the path to each app when you run it.

Answer (score 7):

Consider creating an `/opt` directory, which is another location that custom Unix software would appear by convention.

Comment: `/opt/` is very useful for complete applications whereas `/usr/local/bin/` is more appropriate for standalone command line scripts. It is often preferable to use `/opt/` in instances where a collection of related scripts act as a library (e.g., `/opt/myscriptslib/bin/`).

Comment: Thanx for your advices. I personally created the folder /opt/ to put my software and then I just made  symbolic links to /usr/local/bin for all the executables... then no need to add the /opt/myspecific-soft in the path environment variable.