# OS X - Create a personal bin directory (~/bin) and run scripts without specifying their full path

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

So, what I am trying to do is to create a personal `bin` directory at my home folder. I created the following folder:

```
/Users/thi/bin
```

I put my scripts in this folder, but if I type in the Terminal:

```
myScript
```

It doesn't run.

I was told I have to export this bin path, something related to `echo $PATH`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: see also towards the end of http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98626

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add the following to file `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=/Users/thi/bin:$PATH
```

Then `source ~/.profile`

Note, that you may need to create this file, and because it begins with a `.` it might not be visible in the finder for editing via an application like a text editor.  To list all files including hidden ones, use:

```
ls -la ~/
```

Comment: If I add export PATH=/Users/thi/bin:$PATH to my .bashrc file, is it gonnae work? Is it correct?

Comment: Better use `$HOME/bin` instead of `/Users/thi/bin`. You'll then be able to copy your settings to another machine, where your user name is perhaps different.

Comment: If I type in the terminal: PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH and then type: export PATH. Will it do the trick?

Comment: If you do that, it will change the settings now, but not on future boots. To change the path in a way that survives reboots, you need to include those commands in your `.profile` file.

Comment: Thks!! And why do I have to run "source ~/.profile"? What does it do? @DanielLawson

Comment: `source ~/.profile` will apply the new/changed `.profile` file to your current shell session. You only need to do that to see your changes take effect without opening a new Terminal session.

Comment: Great, thank you all for the answers. I added `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` to my `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Comment: 1) launchd gets its path from '/etc/launchd.conf' or 2) if your scripts don't inherit the $PATH you may need to add 'source "$HOME/.profile"' to the top of your scripts.

Answer (score 10):

If you use bash, add a line like this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

`PATH` is marked for export by default, so you don't need to use `export`.

If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist, bash only reads `~/.bash_profile` when it is invoked as an interactive login shell. `~/.profile` is also used by other shells that might not understand the same configuration options as bash.

Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells by default. When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, it reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`. The terminal emulators on other platforms often open new shells as non-login shells, so for example bash reads `~/.bashrc` but not `~/.bash_profile`. OS X users often use `~/.bash_profile` as the personal configuration file corresponding to `~/.bashrc` on other platforms, but it is also common to source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` or to tell Terminal or iTerm 2 to open new shells as non-login shells.

You can also change the path more globally in `/etc/paths` or `/etc/launchd.conf`, but in many contexts the path will still default to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. And I have only really needed to change the path in shells and text editors.

Comment: Great, thks for the answer. I added `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` to my `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Comment: [You don't need export](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25704/10053), and both `~` (when unquoted) and `$HOME` are expanded before the variable assignment both when using export or a plain assignment.

Comment: Lauri Ranta, what do you prefer personally, `.bash_profile` or `.profile`? Or you have a `.bashrc` in your home directory?

Comment: I used to use only .bash_profile, but now I use .bashrc as my main configuration file and my .bash_profile just contains `. ~/.bashrc`. New shells are opened as non-login shells in the shell mode in emacs and in tmux. I wouldn't use .profile as my main configuration file, because it is also read by other shells like ksh.

Answer (score 3):

You typically would put additional paths after `$PATH` like `PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/bin` because if you don't want to supersede another executable with the same name that might be in `/bin`, etc.

Comment: One might easily argue that you would put `$HOME/bin` at the beginning exactly for that reason. But the key thing is that the order of directories in `$PATH` matters and that the shell will pick the first matching command. Thanks for pointing this out.