# I downloaded a shell executable and man pages from a source I trust. Where should I put them?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, path, binary

I downloaded a binary file for a shell executable, and the corresponding man pages, from a source I trust. Unpacking the archive returns a binary file and some man pages. There's no installer. Which is the "canonical" location to put this kind of stuff? I guess it should be somewhere on my `PATH`. `echo $PATH` returns:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/.../bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Of these, I seem to recall that tampering with `/usr/local/` is considered bad practice. Logically, `Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin` also don't seem appropriate. This leaves me with `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`. Which one should  I use? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Also, do the binary file and the man pages go into the same folder? Or do they go to different folder?

PS I really wonder how much effort would have been to add a damn installer....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The binary file goes in `/usr/local/bin`. Each man page goes in the folder `usr/local/share/man/manN` where `N` is the number at the end of the man page file name. For example, `gdisk.8` should appear in the folder `/usr/local/share/man/man8`. When finished adding all man pages, you should run the command

```
/usr/libexec/makewhatis /usr/local/share/man
```

to update the whatis database stored in the text file `/usr/local/share/man/whatis`. This `whatis` text file is used by the `whatis` and `apropos` commands.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr/local` in general is the place to install user-provided unix-like software.

- For the binaries, see [Where should shell tools be installed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80902/where-should-shell-tools-be-installed) or [Where should shell tools be installed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80902/where-should-shell-tools-be-installed) which both point to `/usr/local/bin`.
- For man pages use `/usr/local/share/man/manN` (with N being the chapter, usually 1 or 8 for commands) and make sure `/usr/local/share/man` is in `/etc/manpaths` (or added as an additional entry in a specific file in `/etc/manpaths.d`).