# Reason for root `/private` heirarchy

Tags: macos, filesystem

What is the reason for the `/private` directory structure located at the root of an OSX system volume?  Why are `/etc`, `/tmp`, and `/var` symlinks to subdirectories of `/private`?

**NOTE** While writing my question, I discovered [this answer to another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/why-is-tmp-a-symlink-to-private-tmp#answer-1096) which seems to address this issue.  I'm going to post my question anyway because it contains the terms that I searched for.  The other question/answer doesn't, prompting me to start writing this question in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate. Don't worry though, your question will still show up in search so anybody searching along the same search terms as you did will still find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer to another, more specific question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/why-is-tmp-a-symlink-to-private-tmp#answer-1096) explains that this directory structure quirk is a vestige of OSX's NextStep heritage.